# How to print Unique Squares Of Numbers In Java 8?

Tags: java, list, java-8, unique, perfect-square

Here is my code to find the unique number and print the squares of it. How can I convert this code to java8 as it will be better to stream API?

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(3, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 5);
HashSet<Integer> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(numbers);

for (Integer value : uniqueValues) {
    System.out.println(value + "\t" + (int)Math.pow(value, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IntStream.of` with `distinct` and `forEach`:

```
IntStream.of(3, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 5)
         .distinct()
         .forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + "\t" +(int)Math.pow(n, 2)));
```

or if you want the source to remain as a `List<Integer>` then you can do as follows:

```
numbers.stream()
       .distinct()
       .forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + "\t" +(int)Math.pow(n, 2)));
```

yet another variant:

```
new HashSet<>(numbers).forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + "\t" +(int)Math.pow(n, 2)));
```

Comment: I want to go with 2nd one.thanks for the answer again

Comment: sorry one question.In 2nd and 3rd which one will be efficient ?

Comment: @NullPointer I'd say the 3rd variant would be more efficient than the 2nd as it doesn't have the stream overhead.

Comment: Don’t be surprised if `System.out.println` turns out to be the most expensive operation and thus, `System.out.println( numbers.stream() .distinct()  .map(n -> n+"\t"+n*n) .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")) );` is even faster. However, only a benchmark can tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(3, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 5);
numbers.stream()
    .distinct()
    .map(n -> String.join("\t",n.toString(),String.valueOf(Math.pow(n, 2))))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Holger comments, in above answers  `System.out.println` looks most expensive operation.

May be we can do it in more faster way like:

```
 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(3, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3, 5);
 System.out.println( numbers.stream()
                     .distinct()
                     .map(n -> n+"\t"+n*n) 
                     .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")) 
                   );
```